# Opening a URL connection works on my local workspace but not on a unix box

Tags: sockets, http, firewall, urlconnection

Following is the code that run absolutely fine when I execute it on my local workspace in office:

```
URL url = new URL(getImageUrl());
InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
```

getImageUrl returns a simple url that can be accessed within the network - http://someurl.png

The resource that I am reading from is an http url - a simple get operation.

This image is easily loaded in the frontend. However, while trying to connect it in the springboot backend project, it fails with the code above.

I can access this image directly within my office network.

However, when I upload my java jar in a unix box and run the service project, this code fails either with connection timed out exception or 'Cannot get input stream from URL!'

Not sure why it would act differently in different environments - both of which are within the office network.

Does the operating system matter here? Do I need to use some encoding when I move from windows to unix operating system for running the same project?

The exception that I get is:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1169) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:933) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
```

This might as well be a firewall issue but just wanted to be sure if I am doing anything wrong in the way I am using ImageIO class?

Also, is this something that an network/machine administrator/superuser can solve?

Comment: What does `getImageUrl()` return?

Comment: a simple image url - htttp.someurl.png

Comment: Check if you are able to access the link in unix env outside your code, probably using `wget`

Comment: What does `getImageUrl()` return? Is that a File path or an HTTP URL? If File, did you check if you have permission to read that file? What's the error/exception that you see on the UNIX box? If the resource you are reading is in your Jar, you will need to read it as a class path resource. Please add all details so your question can be answered correctly.

Comment: The resource is available as a direct url - updated description

Comment: The connection times out when I do a wget using that url directly on the unix box

Comment: However, this is accessible on my local windows workspace within the office network

Comment: `Cannot get input stream from URL!` is not a Java error message. It is one of yours. It conveys no useful information other than failure. Please provide the complete stack trace and the relevant code.

Comment: The unit box cannot physically access that URL. You need to provide more detail

Comment: What details should I provide?

Comment: Please help me figure what can I improve about this question to help lift my question ban?

Comment: i.e. I got banned from asking questions. What else can I add here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that both machines are within the office network doesn't mean that both may be able to get to the (eg different DNS, or firewall rules, etc).

You should check on the box that you can download the image, thus from the terminal (on the linux box) run:

```
wget http://typeOffendingURL.png
```

and you'll probably get the same error as this is a host configuration error, not Java.

Comment: Yes, that's right. It keeps retrying itself. - wget url.png

Comment: What's the solution though, any ideas?

Comment: Start checking the DNS; assuming that your URL is "http://www.example.com/image.png", from your workstation get the IP of the www.example.com and ping it from your linux box. If it's not reachable you must speak with your sysadmin to fix it; if it then add this line (eg: `127.0.0.1 www.example.com` into /etc/hosts on linux box (you need to have root privileges) and try again.

Comment: Ok, but it isn't it weird that the same UI is loading in the frontend (which again is deployed in a similar unix box. And if I do a wget in this unix box, it again takes forever to connect to this url)

Comment: hosts configurations may be very different and for different reasons (eg: dev, qa, prod environments)

Comment: How can I improve this question?

Comment: I don't see any need to improve the question. Why would you?

Comment: Ok, if there is no scope, that's fine. I am just looking for opportunities to improve all my questions